# Performance in Generic Stored Procedure Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have the following class to be called in all my application

```
@Component
public class GenericStoredProcedure 
{

private final DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
GenericStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource){
   this.dataSource = dataSource;
}


public Map executeSimpleProcedure(String procedureName, Map<String, Long> inParams,   Map<String, RowMapperContainer> outParams)
{

    InnerStoredProcedure innerStoredProcedure= new InnerStoredProcedure(dataSource, procedureName,inParams, outParams);

    return innerStoredProcedure.executeProcedure(inParams);
}

/**************************************START OF INNER CLASS*************************************************/
/***********************************************************************************************************/      
/**
 * INNER CLASS 'InnerStoredProcedure' IS ONLY FOR THE USE OF OUTER CLASS GenericStoredProcedure
 * @author mijaz
 *
 */
private class InnerStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure 
{

    public InnerStoredProcedure(DataSource ds, String SQL, Map<String, Long> inParams, Map<String, RowMapperContainer> outParams) 
    {
        setDataSource(ds);
        // setFunction(true);
        setSql(SQL);
        configerParameters(inParams, outParams);
        compile();
    }

    /**
     * Configure the input and output parameters for the stored procedure
     * @param inParams
     * @param outputParamers
     */
    public void configerParameters(Map<String, Long> inParams, Map<String, RowMapperContainer>outputParamers) 
    {
        if (inParams != null && inParams.size() > 0) 
        {
            // entrySet()
            Iterator<String> inParamsIterator = inParams.keySet().iterator();
            while (inParamsIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                String key = inParamsIterator.next();
                declareParameter(new SqlParameter(key, Types.INTEGER));
            }

        }

        Iterator <String> keySetIterator = outputParamers.keySet().iterator();
        while (keySetIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            String key = keySetIterator.next();

            RowMapperContainer rowMapperContainer = (RowMapperContainer) outputParamers.get(key);
            int sqlType = rowMapperContainer.getType();
            if (sqlType == OracleTypes.CURSOR) 
            {
                declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(key,OracleTypes.CURSOR, rowMapperContainer.getRowMapper()));
            }
            else if (sqlType == OracleTypes.VARCHAR) 
            {
                declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(key,OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
            }
            else if (sqlType == OracleTypes.STRUCT) 
            {
                declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(key,OracleTypes.STRUCT,rowMapperContainer.getTypeName(), rowMapperContainer.getSqlReturnType()));
            }
            .....

        }

    }

    public Map executeProcedure(Map inputs) {

        return execute(inputs);
    }
}
/**************************************END OF INNER CLASS 'InnerStoredProcedure'**************************/
/*********************************************************************************************************/
```

In all DAOs,

```
@Component
public class ProductsDAO{

@Autowired
GenericStoredProcedure sp

public List<Item> methodXXX(int id){
   .....
   List items = sp.executeSimpleProcedure(procedure, in, mapper );
}
```

I understand that GenericStoredProcedure is singleton but in the method executeSimpleProcedure an instance of InnerStoredProcedure is created, this makes GenericStoredProcedure thread safe, right?

In a web application, is it optimal to create instances of InnerStoredProcedure?